# Apple Swift Datepicker as keyboard

Tags: swift

I am trying to show a date picker when a text control is clicked using Swift.

I have done this like so:

```
var DatePickerView: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
DatePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
txtBirthdate.inputView = DatePickerView
```

Now when the user taps the text box instead of a keyboard we get a date picker, the problem is with this line:

```
DatePickerView.addTarget(self, action: "handelDatePicker", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

And I handle the control like so:

```
func handelDatePicker()
{
    txtBirthdate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(DatePickerView.date)
}
```

I don't know what is going on, it keeps giving me an invalid selector exception, has anyone figured this out yet, I know Swift is very new.

Comment: use "handelDataPicker" not "handelDataPicker:"

Comment: This isn't a new problem. As @BryanChen Points out, you need to remove the colon (:) from the method signature. The colon represents that the method will have a parameter when in reality it does not.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, but in the actual code that I am using it spelled correctly.

Comment: can you show your actual code?

Comment: @0x7fffffff♦ , I have done that removing colon, still the same issue .

Comment: @BryanChen The only ting missing from the code I posted, is the class declration, the code I posted comes out of viewDidload. But , I guess I can repost the entire class if it will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should wrap the action parameter with the `Selector` initializer:

```
DatePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handelDatePicker"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

I'm copying it verbatim here from your code, but also 'handle' seems to be misspelled.

Comment: I have seen Apple use just a plain string for selector names, so I do not think this is the root of the problem.

Comment: @BrianTracy Perhaps, at the heart of it selectors are just strings. But other than that, I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: I thought I read in apple docs too that you can just use a string, I guess I will try that! The only other thing I can think of is that Xcode is acting crazy because its in beta

Comment: Turns out, some of the apple documentation is wrong, add the Selector initializer worked like a champ. I hope they update the docs before the final of xcode ships.